# Complex matrix decomposition: Cholesky?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $A\ge 0$ be a positive definite matrix. Can I always find a matrix B such that 
$$ BB^\ast=A, \qquad BB^t=0,$$
where $B^t$ is the transpose and $B^\ast $ is the conjugate transpose? If yes, is this decomposition numerically efficient?

I tried construct $B$ as a complex combination of the Cholesky transform of $A$ but was not successful.

Comment: It is even not possible for a positive scalar. Why are you asking?

Comment: You know that such a $B$ would need to be nonsingular and singular at the same time.